# How to Repeat Transposing A Query Output matching values from a range reference over the whole column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, google-query-language

I need to transpose column `B` values where column `A` values are matching over the entire column.

I tested this but it's not working:

[image: QUERY TRANSPOSE OUTPUT]

```
=transpose(QUERY(A2:B,"select Col2 WHERE Col1 MATCHES '"&A2:A&"' "))
```

Current output:

| Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | A1 | A1 | A2 | A3 |
| 7 | A2 |  |  |  |
| 7 | A3 |  |  |  |
| 8 | b1 |  |  |  |
| 8 | b2 |  |  |  |
| 8 | b3 |  |  |  |
| 9 | c1 |  |  |  |
| 9 | c2 |  |  |  |
| 9 | c3 |  |  |  |
| 9 | c4 |  |  |  |

Needed Output:

| Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 | Item 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | A1 | A1 | A2 | A3 |  |
| 7 | A2 | b1 | b2 | b3 |  |
| 7 | A3 | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| 8 | b1 |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | b2 |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | b3 |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | c1 |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | c2 |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | c3 |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | c4 |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,torow(filter(B:B,A:A=c))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! It works. I'll test it now on large dataset and come back to accept your solution asap. Many thanks!

Comment: Seems to works all right for my larger dataset. Many thanks again! Be well!